# Declared and populated Object in JavaScript is undefined error

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Can you please help me see why obj is undefined, even though it is assigned with properties?

Error I get:

[image]

Function:

```
function arrayToAlaObjectOfArrays(data) {

  //We filter out all blank records (elements) returned in data
  data = data.filter(record => !record.every(col => col==''));

  let headers = data.shift(); //Cut out firs member record into column headers

  console.log('data: ' + data);
  console.log('headers: ' + headers);

   let arrNew = data.map(record => {
    let obj = {};
    record.forEach((cell,i) => {
      obj[headers[i]] = cell;
      console.log('header[i]' + headers[i] + '  cell: ' + cell + ' obj: ' + obj[0]);
    });

    console.log('obj: ' + obj[0].name);
    return obj;
  
  });

  console.log('arrNew: ' + arrNew);

  return arrNew;
  
}
```

Comment: `let obj = {};` makes `obj` an object, not an array...

Comment: `obj[0].name` ---> `obj.name`

Comment: If you have `obj[headers[i]] = cell;` and `header[i]` is only `id`, `name`, or `city_code` (as seen in the log), then `obj[0].name` cannot work since none of the keys added to the object is a zero.

Comment: Thanks all! Yes, I made this mistake only in the checkpoints logging. The real mistake was to implicitly stringify obj by concatenation in the console.log statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
  const arrNew = data.map(record => {
    const obj = {};
    record.forEach((cell, i) => {
      obj[headers[i]] = cell;
    });
  });
  console.log(arrNew[0].name);
```

to print the first name in the new data (though if there are no entries, this too will throw an error), or simply

```
console.log(obj.name);
```

within the `.map()` to print out each name as the objects get generated.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from mistakenly treating the object as an array in debugging console.log statements, I failed to see the obj results in the console as I implicitly stringified it by concatenation in this statement:

```
console.log('obj: ' + obj);
```

Working function is:

```
function arrayToAlaObjectOfArrays(data) {

  //We filter out all blank records (elements) returned in data
  data = data.filter(record => !record.every(col => col==''));

  let headers = data.shift(); //Cut out firs member record into column headers

  let arrNew = data.map(record => {
    let obj = {};
    record.forEach((cell,i) => {
      obj[headers[i]] = cell;
    });
    return obj;
  });

  console.log(arrNew);

  return arrNew;
```